# codeigniter validation error with field "required"

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, field, required

i have a problem with the validation form. It does not work if i put "required", example:

controller:

```
public function updateBenefit(){
    $result = array();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('beneficio', 'Nombre del Beneficio', 'required|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('info', 'Info', 'alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('descrip', 'Descripción', 'alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('orden', 'Orden', 'integer');

    // $this->form_validation->set_rules('fecha', 'Fecha', 'date_valid');

    $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'El campo %s es requerido');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){

        if (isset($_POST['id'])){

            $idb = $_POST['id'];
            $benefit = BeneficiosManager::getInstance()->getHome($idb);

            $result['message'] = "Se ha modificado el Beneficio con éxito"; 

        } else{
            $benefit = BeneficiosManager::getInstance()->create();

            $result['message'] = "Se ha cargado el Beneficio con éxito"; 
        }

        $benefit->nombre = ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['beneficio']));
        $benefit->content = ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['descrip']));
        $benefit->intro = ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['info']));
        $benefit->active = $_POST['optionsRadios2'];
        $benefit->orden = $_POST['orden'];

        // $benefit->date = $_POST['fecha'];

        BeneficiosManager::getInstance()->save($benefit);

        }else{
            //no se validaron los datos ingresados
            $result['message'] = "Error validación";
        }

        echo json_encode($result);
}
```

view:

```
    {extends file='admin/base/base.tpl'}

{block name='content'}

<h3>Cargar Beneficio </h3>
</br>
<form action="{site_url()}admin/updateBenefit" class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Beneficio</label>
      <div class="controls">
         <input type="text" name="beneficio" value="" class="m-wrap medium" />
         <span class="help-inline">Nombre del Beneficio</span>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Info</label>
      <div class="controls">
         <textarea name="info" class="medium m-wrap" rows="3"></textarea>
         <span class="help-inline">Información Clave</span>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Descripción</label>
      <div class="controls">
         <textarea name="descrip" class="large m-wrap" rows="3"></textarea>
         <span class="help-inline">Descripción del Beneficio</span>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Activo</label>
      <div class="controls">
            <label class="radio line">
               <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2" value="1"/>Si</input>
            </label>
            <label class="radio line">   
               <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2" value="0"/>No</input>
            </label>
         <span class="help-inline">Ofrecer Beneficio</span>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Orden</label>
      <div class="controls">
         <input type="text" name="orden" value="" class="m-wrap small" />
         <span class="help-inline">Prioridad del Beneficio</span>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Fecha</label>
      <div class="controls">
         <input type="text" name="fecha" value="{$smarty.now|date_format}" class="m-wrap medium" />
         <span class="help-inline"></span>
      </div>
   </div>   

   <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit" class="btn blue"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Guardar</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn">Cancelar</button>
   </div>

</form>

{/block}
```

what might the problem be?

if i remove the "required" field, the form validates... but if i put it, it doesn't... i don't know what else to try, can't understand why this is happening

the code is working now, thanks to @Jonathan that corrected me, and i was also making an imput mistake when i was trying this method. I was trying to put two words in the same field (i.e: bon vivir); so the correct input would be: bonvivir.

Comment: Do you have a field called "title" ?

Comment: `it does not work` is not a useful error description. What exactly doesn't work? Do you get any errors? What's the expected result?

Comment: A likely problem is that you're missing some of the code required. Please read the manual entry in full: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: @user1281385 yes, i have a field named "title"

Comment: @AmalMurali when i use the "required" field, my form doesn't validate, i get a validation error. If i remove the "required" field, the form validates, but i really need to use the required field

Comment: @DamienPirsy i don't think that is the problem, i will edit my post with full code. thnx!

Comment: Can you post your view?

Comment: @Jeemusu yes, i will post the view inmediatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you are using "title" as the name of your real title input element. Because I found you use this code to assign your title.

```
$benefit->title = ucfirst(strtolower(trim($_POST['beneficio'])));
```

So you may want to try to use

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('beneficio', 'Nombre del Beneficio', 'required|alpha');
```

instead.

I am not sure I had the right guess. Just give it a go. Hope this helps.

Comment: IKR? Why is 'title' required if you aren't doing anything with it?

Comment: @Jonathan i've changed the field "title" to "nombre", but it still not working, same validation errors are displayed

Comment: @jcorry title is required because you can't upload a benefit without a name. It's a website about people and prizes, the prizes are benefits so we need to keep them with names.

Comment: @Jimena it doesn't look like your controller is doing ANYTHING with a $_POST element 'title' except confirming that it's there...the only place you're using $_POST['title'] is in the form validation...

Comment: @jcorry i've changed "title" for "nombre", but i can't understand your point, what do you mean by saying that i use "title"(or "nombre") only for the form validation?

Comment: The form validation is looking for an element in the post array named 'title'. Nowhere else in the controller method is $_POST['title'] used for anything. So, the ONLY use of that field is to validate that it's there...why is it required if it's only purpose is confirming that it's there?

Comment: @jcorry well, i've made a mistake and already corrected it, "title" is no longer needed because that was the name of the field in the DB, bot in my form, and to validate i need to have the form name. So now i will edit my code, but it's still not working!

Comment: @Jonathan thank you for the observation, here: $this->form_validation->set_rules('beneficio', 'Nombre del Beneficio', 'required|alpha');
here i was putting the name of the field from de DB, no the name from the field in the form..... i've changed it, but still same errors!

Comment: Hi @Jimena, sorry I didn't catch up this. The first parameter of set_rules() is the name of your element which needs to be validated. Nothing about your DB, just your form.